# div resizable,drag and drop with any size. (Not overload div any other div)

Tags: jquery, css

Want to drag and drop and resizable grid (or div) like `https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/`

Requirement is :

1) Resizable div

2) drag and drop div (not overrload on another div)

This is working using gridstack.js. But There is one problem I face.

Example :
Screen size width 900px;

I will put any object on width 900px screen. 
Now, I want to this object size (using resizable) 890px. It is not possible in grid stack because it is calculate 900px screen in 12 part like bootstrap. So, it is given object size (825px) in this case.

I had change gridstack css for 100 part. but resizable is not working. Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jayesh14/qv523gkz/20/)

Have any solution in gridstack? Or any other best way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/):

From the left menu see interactions or these links:
1) [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)
2) [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)